# ArangoDB: Spring Data and Graph Model Support

Tags: java, graph, spring-data, arangodb

Does ArangoDB Spring Data support a Graph data model or just Documents and Collections?

I'm playing around with ArangoDB and Java to learn more about it.

I'm using Spring-Boot and ArangoDB-Spring-Data with a very basic Character and Location domain model.  When using ArangoDB-Spring-Data, the Character and Location repositories save the domain models as only Collections as seen in the ArangoDB UI.  I would like for ArangoDB-Spring-Data to persist the domain models as a Graph model.

Is is possible to persist the domain models as a Graph model or do I have to do this manually with the JDBC driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no support in spring-data-arangodb for named graphs. It does exists a feature request [issue on github](https://github.com/arangodb/spring-data/issues/76) but there are currently no plans if and when this feature is coming.

If you want so save your entities in a named graph you have to use the underlying driver. It can be accessed over method `driver()` in `ArangoOperations`.

Comment: driver() is interesting.

Comment: Does this is open for a MR ? I really need this feature